# Calculating Leibniz formula for determinants without the sign function

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, determinant

Given a square matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ it is known from Leibniz's formula that $det(A)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}{sign(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^{n}{a_{\sigma(i), i}}}$ where $sign$ is the sign function of the permutation. Even though this formula contains summation of $n!$ terms, it can be calculated in $O(n^3)$. I have a similar operator $F(A)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}{a_{\sigma(i), i}}}$ which is very similar to Leibniz's formula, but without the sign function. For $2 \times 2$ matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c& d\end{pmatrix}$ and $det(A)=ad-cb$ so we can change the sign of $b$ and define  $A'=\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ c& d\end{pmatrix}$ to get $det(A')=ad+cb$. However for $3 \times 3$ matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e& f \\ g & h & i\end{pmatrix}$,  $det(A)=a\begin{vmatrix} e & f\\ h& i \end{vmatrix} - b\begin{vmatrix} d & f\\ g & i \end{vmatrix} + c\begin{vmatrix} d & e\\ g & h \end{vmatrix}$ and when I negate one entrance of the matrix it affects the value of other determinants and it seems there is no way to get $F(A)$ using negation on certain entrances in A. Is there an efficient way to calculate it without calculating the naive summation?

Comment: Perhaps you should read what this says about the computation of permanents. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)

Comment: The related entry on [Computing the Permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent) gives the best known exact algorithm as $O(2^{n-1}n)$.

Comment: Thank you it is indeed what I was looking for